# How to make Bidirectional OneToMany relationship with JoinTable in Doctrine?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have read the [official docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/association-mapping.html) and many questions here. I also tried blindly few things without results. Please do not focus on "why I need it" but whether this is possible:

I have these 2 entities:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Payout
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private ?int $id;
    
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\BalanceLog")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="payouts_balance_logs",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="payout_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="balance_log_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
     *      )
     */
    private Collection $balance_logs;

}


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class BalanceLog
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private ?int $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Payout")
     */
    private ?Payout $payout;

}
```

One `BalanceLog` CAN (but does not have to) point to a `Payout`. And every `Payout` has at least one `BalanceLog`. This all is achieved with `payouts_balance_logs` table, where `balance_log_id` is unique (meaning a single balance log can point to only one payout)

I can easily make a bi-directional ManyToMany relationship, but then I have `BalanceLog::$payouts` collection, not a single object.

I can also make it bi-directional OneToMany/ManyToOne without using `JoinTable`, but then EVERY `BalanceLog` will need its nullable `payout_id` column.

I think that what I want has to be common and achievable. Please help, thanks!

Comment: I think you will need to use a ManyToMany in order to have a bidirectional relationship with a join table. You might be able to achieve your desired effect by making one of the fields in the many to many table unique.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the downside to having a field with a null value?

Comment: @wetmarble its ugly design to have a nullable value only because doctrine is limited. I am used to coding without frameworks and this is exactly one of the reasons why I often prefer to do things "vanilla" and not with such abstraction level.